# C# service: error starting service: missing standard constructor

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm trying to start my previously installed service using `net start servicename`.

I can confirm that the service was installed successfully, there are entries in the registry and in the service overview within the administration tools area.

Actually I can see an error message within the event log telling me that the service could not be loaded because it does not have an standard (parameter-less) constructor.

The last two lines of the strack trace are the following

```
bei Test.Service.DbService.OnStart(String[] args)
bei System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQ...
```

I implemented the service in the following way:

```
public partial class DbService : ServiceBase
{
    public DbService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ServiceName = "Service1";
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
            serviceHost.Close();

        Uri[] baseAddress = new Uri[]{
        //new Uri("http://localhost:8000"),
        new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")};

        string PipeName = "Test";

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Kernel), baseAddress);

        // Add a mex endpoint 
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/DatabaseService/mex");
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);



        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDatabase), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), PipeName);

        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and that's how I call the service initially:

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new DbService() //new instance of class implementing the service!
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Can you confirm that I'm doing this right?

Comment: See here, it may help: http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2011/04/19/inversion-of-control-and-wcf.aspx

Comment: Have you remembered to install all dependent assemblies (if any of the dependencies have changed since the first install)?

Comment: There is one dependency: I extracted the service contract within an own DLL, but which is shipped using the Installer (it's listed as dependency and copied to the installation folder too).

Comment: It isn't complaining about the service, it is complaining about the code in OnStart().  I suspect the Kernel type is the problem but that's just a guess.

Comment: I got it, it was so simple that I just was aware of that.

The key is: i re-read the error message a couple of times until i recognized that it was telling me that the "service-type" does not contain a standard constructor what actually is completely correct. 

this is the line of interest:

    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Kernel), baseAddress);

the class "Kernel" does not contain an standard constructor, thats it.
I added a constructor without any parameters to it and its working.

Thanks for your ideas and your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it was so simple that I just was aware of that. The key is: i re-read the error message a couple of times until i recognized that it was telling me that the "service-type" does not contain a standard constructor what actually is completely correct. this is the line of interest: serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Kernel), baseAddress); the class "Kernel" does not contain an standard constructor, thats it. I added a constructor without any parameters to it and its working. Thanks for your ideas and your support!